# Python/Tkinter: pack equivalent of grid_remove(), eg. pack_remove()?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Is there a pack equivalent of the grid_remove() method where a widget's original pack() settings are restored on a re-pack()?

Use case: When I show a packed widget that has been hidden via pack_forget(), I would like to have the widget re-packed with its original pack settings when I issue the widget.pack() show request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no equivalent. There is only `pack_forget` which doesn't remember where the widget was when you restore it. If I need this sort of feature I just use the grid geometry manager.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

b = Button(root, text="Delete me", command=lambda: b.grid_remove())
b.grid(row=0,column=0)

root.mainloop()

grid_remove works
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It explicitly asked for the equivalent of `grid_remove()` for the **pack** layout manager. It's obvious that asker is already aware of the function you suggest.